# appSettings and ConfigurationManager.AppSettings issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have searched the site, and while I found some very useful information, I couldn't figure out what is going on with my code.  I have the following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="APIKey" value="23e24c73feed7ca0f6afd876575842de"/>
    <add key="Secret" value="################################"/>
    <add key="Callback" value="http://localhost:55994/"/>
    <add key="Suffix" value="My3Words"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have snipped out the stuff in system.web and system.webServer, but it's the default settings generated in an ASP.NET MVC app.

I am trying to access the keys in the  section (this is a simple Facebook application using FB Connect).

In my code, I have the following line:

```
return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"];
```

and it is returning a null.  I can't quite figure out what is going on.  I have the requisite:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using System.Configuration;
```

at the top of my .cs file.  I have a very strong suspicion the error exists post-keyboard (i.e. in my brain), but I can't solve this one.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling ConfigurationManager from an external DLL?

Comment: I am calling ConfigurationManager from a .cs file which is being called into from my HomeController.cs

Comment: There's not much that can really go wrong between web.config and  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings so it's a bit of a strange one. To cehck you're definitely using the correct config file try making your web.config invalid XML and verify your web site fails?

Comment: Quick and dirty way to make the config file invalid?

Comment: @Brandon - Throw an unencoded & in somewhere.

Comment: Any chance you have another web.config in the directory where your .cs file is? Maybe Try Configuration c = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~"); to open the one in the root directory.

Answer (score 30):

Have you tried using the [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx):

```
return System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"];
```

This is the preferred option for using config files in a web app - it handles things like nested config files, etc.

Comment: This did not work even though I had multiple web.config files.  I have moved the <appSettings> to the other file and both methods work fine for getting the key.  Thanks for the answer...I am an idiot.

Comment: Ok, so which folder was this web.config in? Was it at least under (in the folder tree) the location the code was running from? You're not an idiot ;)

Comment: I had this same issue as @Brandon. This answer was the solution for me. My project was a WCF Service Library and when I hosted it in IIS and moved the configuration to Web.config from App.config.

Comment: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings simply wraps ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, so this isn't going to help.  In general I'd prefer ConfigurationManager.AppSettings and ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings to the equivalents in WebConfigurationManager, especially in class libraries.

Comment: Kind of Joe: The `WebConfigurationManager` doesn't just "wrap ConfigurationManager" it also provides you with a way to read and work with the hierarchy of configuration files that are used by IIS when hosting a web application - as well as understanding the web specific sections nicely.

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio creates 2 web.config files for MVC. 1 at the root, and the other in the Views folder.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you're using the correct Web.Config file? You probably want to use the one at the application root, not the one in the Views directory.

[ASP.NET MVC and two Web.config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517086/asp-net-mvc-and-two-web-config-files)

Comment: feel like a real muppet for doing this! thanks for putting the basics up :)

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the Build Action of the web.config file is "None".  I have seen this problem if the build action is "Embedded Resource".

Comment: It was set to "content" but I set to "None" with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Does your machine.config have the requisite AppSettings section. It should look something like (version numbers would be different):

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
       <section name="appSettings"
          type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System,          Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Are you sure you're using the correct web.config? What does [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.appsettingssection.settings.aspx) look like?

Answer (score 0):

I bet u r using the right syntax to access them when you write: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"];

Try this format for the web config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
<appSettings>
    <add key="Key1" value="Val1"/>
    <add key="Key2" value="Val2"/>
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    ......
    ......
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"/>
    <authorization>
        ......
    </authorization>

    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Data"/>
            <add namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
            <add namespace="System.IO"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/></system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have two project in my solution first i add app.config file in class library project which all instances is call from console application i added these entries in config file in class lib project

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="userName" value="user2" /> 
<add key="emilsLimit" value="50" /> 
</appSettings>
```

it was throwing null exception when i get these in a class in class library project but when i delete app.config from class Library project and added in Console project it works.Cheers

Note: Class lib project reference is added in console

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("APIKey");
```