# MVC 3 WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"] returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, web-config, appsettings

May be it's a stupid  but seems mvc has a bug with web.configs.

I put in Web.config (also I've tried to put keys in web.debug.config) several appsettings keys
But

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

as well

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

returns null.

I looked via debugger in AppSettings.AllKeys - it sees the right keys but returns the null.

What is the problem with AppSettings in mvc?

Answer (score 2):

oh, I've found the mistake. 
The problem was in key names, keys were created using copy-paste and it is not noticeable when some keys have the space before closing ", for example **key="HPPRequestUrl "**

Answer (score 0):

Here is someone with similiar problems. maybe it helps [appSettings and ConfigurationManager.AppSettings issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712068/appsettings-and-configurationmanager-appsettings-issue)

Answer (score 0):

> I looked via debugger in AppSettings.AllKeys - it sees the right keys but returns the null.

Probably you have a cyrillic "C" character or a typo in the key name. Try to copy the key name from the AllKeys property using debugger.

Comment: no all keys have english names, no cyrillic characters, I have a bunch of keys and all of them configuration manager returns as null.

Answer (score 0):

In your webconfig you should have something like this:

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="key" value="x" /> 
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And then you can retrieve your value by wrtiting:

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

Comment: my web config:
`<appSettings>
    <add key="HPPRequestUrl " value="https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php" />
...
</appSettings>
`
I'm getting appsettings in this way:

`FormAction = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HPPRequestUrl"];`