# WebHost4Life host migrated my .NET MVC site and now membership functionality does not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7, migration

My MVC site was working fine at Webhost4life until they migrated to the new platform with IIS7. Now the Login feature which my site has to allow employees of the site's company to perform back office functionality does not work. It simply does nothing and returns no error. Looking at it in Fiddler does not seem to reveal anything unusual. Is there a config setting that needs to be made to get this to work with IIS7. Support for the hosting company has not been much help. Please reply with suggestions - I'm desperate to get this working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhost4life tried to migrate my sites but failed so miserably I jumped ship. I assume your mvc app connects to a database? Who knows what WH4L did. First, check the settings in the web.config- maybe they left out some connection data. Here's where your web.config is located [ASP.NET MVC and two Web.config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517086/asp-net-mvc-and-two-web-config-files) . If this doesn't help post the error message.

Comment: who did you switch to and were you satisfied with the result.

Comment: I switched to Arvixe (blind guess but really lucked out - they are amazing). WH4L migrated my sites and SQL Servers to the point they were unusable. Google 'webhost4life migration' and look as the mass of dissatisfaction. I wrote about my experience http://bit.ly/9NzveA

Comment: Thanks - I decided to dump them as well and went with SoftSysHosting which has been a great experience so far.

Answer (score 0):

The MachineKey has changed unless you specifically set it in your Web.Config. If you cannot get the old MachineKey and set it in your web.config I'm assuming your going to have to reset all your passwords so they get hashed with the new machine key.