# Getting database connection error in three tier architechture in mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, 3-tier

I'm trying to implement basic three tier architecture with mvc 3. but getting an error while running the solution ( showing no error while building the solution). The organization of my projects & error message can be seen in the attached image.[image]

Please help.

OK guys, This is an update for.

As specified by some comments, I copied the original connection string from app.config to my web.config file & getting this error as shown in the image.
[image]

I tried to search a lot but no clue! Any help will be highly appropriated.

Comment: How your connection string looks like, in the web.config file?

Comment: I just added this to my web.config file.. <connectionStrings> <add name="Conn" connectionString="data source=(local)/sqlexpress; initial catalog=NORTHWND;"/> </connectionStrings> but still getting the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maarten is right. you always copied the normal connection string (that is a part of entity-connection string). you need to copy the entire connection string that was generated in your **App.config** file in **Data** layer and paste it in the **web.config** file in your **presentation** layer. the entity-connection string like as :

```
<add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Northwind;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Blister01;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**don't copy-paste it, it is just a sample**

Comment: The primary problem is solved now, but still having some trouble with passing the data to the view! But that is another issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string you've copied is a normal connection string. You are using an edmx file which means you need an entity-connection string.

You need to copy the entity-connectionstring into the web.config. You can find the EF-connectionstring in the app.config file in the Data layer where EF added it for you.

Comment: The primary problem is solved now, but still having some trouble with passing the data to the view! But that is another issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you just add connection string `connectionStrings` section in `web.config` in **Presentation layer**!

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Ey2.png)

Comment: I just added this to my web.config file..  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Conn" connectionString="data source=(local)/sqlexpress; initial catalog=NORTHWND;"/>
    </connectionStrings> but still getting the problem.

Comment: yes, copy connectionStrings and past in **Presentation layer**

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand, could you please elaborate the term past in presentation layer

Comment: Can it be related to missing reference or something like that?

Comment: i have same problem facing earlier that time i will found solution this way and working.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: try with this

```
<add name="NORTHWINDEntities" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="data source=(local)/sqlexpress; initial catalog=NORTHWND;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

Comment: Still not working. I used entity framework's database first model, while working on a single project, i never got any error like this, as far I can remember, I didn't had to use connection string! I'm getting this error while trying to synchronize three projects together.

Comment: Are you editing the web.config file in the project's root directory? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517086/asp-net-mvc-and-two-web-config-files

Comment: If so, try to remove the connection string from it. After that, remove your Entity Data Mode file(.edmx) and add generate it again from the database. (Probably this will solve your problem.)