# Trying to read from web.config - getting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my web.config I have the following:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="authorizedUsers" value="jeff,jason,bob"/>
  </appSettings>
```

In my _Layout.cshtml I have the following:

```
@{
        List<String> authList = new List<string>();
        authList = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authorizedUsers"].Split(',').ToList();

        if (authList.Any(u=>u == this.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin")</li>
        }                               
}
```

When I run this I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with this alternatively you can assign the List into `ViewBag.authList ` from server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you've put your setting in the wrong web.config. Double check you placed it in the appSettings section of the web.config located at project level and not the one located within the Views folder.

[image]

Comment: That was it!  Why do they have 2 web.config files?

Comment: @webdad3 The web.config in the View folder does a few things. Most significantly it blocks direct access to your views. Checkout David's answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517086/asp-net-mvc-and-two-web-config-files